# How avoid timeout exception in a thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, svn

when I execute [this code](http://wiki.svnkit.com/Printing_Out_A_Subversion_Repository_Tree) (obviously with my repos., username & password)inside the main() all is well:

```
      ....
       String url = "http://svn.svnkit.com/repos/svnkit/trunk/doc";
      String name = "anonymous";
        String password = "anonymous";

        SVNRepository repository = null;
        try {
            repository = SVNRepositoryFactory.create( SVNURL.parseURIDecoded( url ) );
            ISVNAuthenticationManager authManager = SVNWCUtil.createDefaultAuthenticationManager( name , password );
           repository.setAuthenticationManager( authManager );
           SVNNodeKind nodeKind = repository.checkPath( "" ,  -1 );
          ....
```

But when I execute this code inside a Thread I get the following error:

> svn: E175002: timed out waiting for server

I tried to set my Thread with max priority but this not worked.
What can I do to solve this problem?

Comment: In general, thread priorities do very little to nothing -- especially if a thread is waiting on a resource such as your SVN server.

Answer (score 1):

The timeout is occurring not because of the thread, but because the SVN API can't connect to your server. Make sure that the machine that's calling this code has access to your repository.

Threads never throw timeout exceptions themselves. Timeout exceptions imply some kind of problem in network I/O with an unreachable server.

Comment: If it's true what you say. Why with the same machine, when the code is executed inside tha main() all is ok and when is executed outiside it, I get that error?